# Como llamar a 2 archivos desde el bean

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsf

Tengo 2 archivos, archivo1 y archivo2 y tengo un bean, mi pregunta es como puedo crear una condición en el bean para saber en que archivo estoy, es decir, si estoy en archivo1 bloquear un menú y si está en archivo2 dejar en menú normal.

Saludos.

Comment: Tu pregunta es demasiado ambigua. ¿Estás trabajando en Java o Javascript? ¿Qué es lo que has intentado? ¿Tienes algún error específico? ¿Lo que quieres realizar es del lado del servidor o del cliente?

Comment: Gracias por preocuparte, acabo de solucionarlo ahora mismo, estoy con java, y al final ha sido una tonteria, lo he arreglado con un actionlistener @skw